# how to search the entire string and format correctly

Tags: php

I'm trying to do this code.

Supposed I have a string with value 1.323,30 or 1,323,30 or 1.323.30

I want to change that to the correct format that was 1323.30 always.

I made this code but that's an alternative way to resolve that, but I want to resolve it without sending to the user a message.

```
if((isset($p["valor"])) && preg_match("/^[0-9,]+$/", $p["valor"])) {
    $valor = str_replace(",", ".", $p['valor']);
}else{
    $bnc->rollBack();
    echo json_encode(array('ret' => '0', 'msg' => $erros['invalidvalue']));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why not fix the code that _creates_ those numbers so that it doesn't allow anything other than the format you want? What are you doing that the data can be all these different formats? (Especially 1,234,56 is crazy, which locale uses that?)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple `preg_replace`. The replace function can take inputs in the form of `array` for all three of the parameters (pattern, replacement, & input) and returns an array.

**Code**

```
$numbers = [
    "1.323,30",
    "1,323,30",
    "1.323.30",
];

$numbers = preg_replace(
    ["/[,.](\d{3})/", "/[,.](\d\d)$/"],
    ["$1", ".$1"],
    $numbers
);

print_r($numbers);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1323.30
    [1] => 1323.30
    [2] => 1323.30
)
```

**Regex 1**

```
[,.](\d{3}) : Matches a comma OR a period.
              Followed by three digits in a capture group
```

**Regex 2**

```
[,.](\d\d)$ : Matches a comma or a period.
              Followed by two digits in a capture group.
              Finishing with the end of the string.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this approach because I had already done this function before, but [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573622/steven)'s answer is **a lot** cleaner.

```php
function alwaysValidNumber($string){
      $dot_pos = strpos($string, '.');
      $comma_pos = strpos($string, ',');
    
      if ($dot_pos !== false && $comma_pos !== false && $dot_pos < $comma_pos) {
        $string = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $string));
      }else if ($comma_pos !== false && $dot_pos === false) {
        $pos = strrpos($string, ',');
        if($pos !== false)
        {
          $string = substr_replace($string, '.', $pos, 1);
        }
      }else if ($dot_pos !== false && $comma_pos === false) {
        while (substr_count($string, '.') > 1) {
          $pos = strpos($string, '.');
          if ($pos !== false) {
            $string = substr_replace($string, '', $pos, 1);
          }
        }
      }
      $string = str_replace(',', '', $string);
      return $string;
}
```

Example:

```php
$values = [
   '10.0000,0',
   '1,323.30',
   '1,323,30',
   '1.323.30',
   '1.32',
   '1,32',
];
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
  $number = alwaysValidNumber($value);
  echo $number . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
100000.0
1323.30
1323.30
1323.30
1.32
1.32
```